# label pandas pivot table series in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot

I have a pandas pivot table.
What I need is to make a line chart, where every series will be labeled from pivot table column.

```
self.VergebenDF = pd.read_sql_table(
                  "vergeben",
                  columns = ['vergeben_no', 'b_nummer', 't_datum', 'b_dauer', 'b_art'],
                  con=self.Engine)
    names = {1: "Alex", 2: "Olga", 3: "Vasya"}

    self.VergebenDF["month"] = self.VergebenDF.t_datum.dt.strftime('%m.%Y')
    self.VergebenDF["b_name"] = self.VergebenDF.b_nummer.map(names)

    pvt = self.VergebenDF.pivot_table(index=["month"], columns=["b_name"], values="b_dauer", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)

    self.axes.title.set_text('First Plot')
    self.axes.plot(pvt)
    self.axes.legend(loc='upper left')
```

So I need 3 lines with corresponding legends: Alex, Olga, Vasya.

I tried so:

```
self.axes.plot(pvt, label=list(names.values()))
```

But the result is not as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let pandas handle the names by plotting the pivot table using the `pandas.DataFrame.plot` function.  To avoid creating a separate plot pass the axes object to the plot function.

So in your case the line in your code that plots would become:

```
pvt.plot(ax=self.axes)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I found the way to build all columns one by one:

```
for name in names.values():
    self.axes.plot(pvt[name], label=name)
```

[image]

Maybe you know the way to build all columns from pivot tables in one command.

Comment: I haven't used a pivot table in pandas but it looks like it is Dataframe still. Could you plot it `pvt.plot()` instead?

Comment: @MicahJohnson the point is I use embedded pyplot with wxPython and have to use it via Axes.plot()

Comment: If you have the axes object you can pass it to the function. e.g.
`pvt.plot(ax=ax)`

Comment: @MicahJohnson Yeah, it works! Please make the answer and I vote for it :) Thanks a lot!